# Complex number and polar coordinates

Tags: complex-numbers

True or false: the polar coordinates of $-1-i$ are $-\sqrt{2}\operatorname{cis}\frac{\pi}{4}$

In my opinion it's true:
$\tan\theta=\frac{-1}{-1}=1\Rightarrow \theta=\frac{5\pi}{4}$, $r=\sqrt{(-1)^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{2}$

Therefore we get: $z=\sqrt{2}\operatorname{cis}\frac{5\pi}{4}=\sqrt{2}(\cos\frac{5\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{5\pi}{4})=\sqrt{2}(-\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-i\sin\frac{\pi}{4})=-\sqrt{2}\operatorname{cis}\frac{\pi}{4}$
that means it's true. But it was written in the algebra book that because of $-2$, it's not polar coordinate. Is the proof right?

Comment: The polar coordinate form for any complex number $x+iy=re^{it}$ requires that $r$ be a non-negative real number.

Comment: It is customary, I think, that cis shows the actual angle of the vector, perhaps up to an additiona multiple of $\;2\pi\;$ ,and you don't mess with signs. In this case, the angle must be $\;\frac{5\pi}4\;$ or even $\;-\frac{3\pi}4\;$ (plus some multiple of $\;2\pi\;$ if you will), so that everybody will know by it where the vector is located.

Answer (score 1):

> Notice:
>
> $$z=\Re[z]+\Im[z]i=|z|e^{\varphi i}=|z|\cos(\varphi)+|z|\sin(\varphi)i$$
>
> Where:
>
> - $\Re[z]$ is the real part of the number $z$
> - $\Im[z]$ is the imaginary part of the number $z$
> - $|z|$ is the abolsute value of $z$ and defined as $|z|:=\sqrt{\Re^2[z]+\Im^2[z]}$
> - $\varphi$ is the argument of $z$ and defined as $\varphi:=\arg[z]$

So, when we have the number $s=-1-i$, we get that:

$$s=-1-i=|-1-i|e^{\arg[-1-i]i}=|-1-i|\cos(\arg[-1-i])+|-1-i|\sin(\arg[-1-i])i$$

Now, when we solve the abolsute value, we get that:

$$|s|=|-1-i|=\sqrt{\Re^2[-1-i]+\Im^2[-1-i]}=\sqrt{(-1)^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt{2}$$

Now, when we solve the argument, we get that:

$$\varphi=\arg[-1-i]=\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{\Im[-1-i]}{\Re[-1-i]}\right)=\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{-1}{-1}\right)=\pi+\arctan(1)=\frac{5\pi}{4}$$

So, when $\color{red}{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$

(this 'changes' the argument, not the absolute value because that has to be $|z|\in\mathbb{R}^+_0$):

$$-1-i=\sqrt{2}e^{\left(2\pi k+\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)i}=\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi k+\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)+\sqrt{2}\sin\left(2\pi k+\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)i$$

Answer (score 1):

No, it's false. The $r$ part must be positive and is computed by
$$
r=\sqrt{(-1-i)(-1+i)}=\sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt{2}
$$

This already answers the true/false question. If you want to find the $\theta$ part, you need to find $\theta$ such that
$$
\cos\theta=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\quad\sin\theta=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
and this is clearly
$$
\theta=\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{5\pi}{4}
$$